# Firefox profile cannot be loaded...profile created but still not able to launch?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, .profile

I created a new sudoer on my Ubuntu machine and logged in. Now when I launch Firefox it gives the error that Firefox profile cannot be loaded. I looked for the solutions then I got the way to create one:

```
sudo firefox -P
```

lets me create a new profile. I created the new profile and I launched the Firefox from that window. Now, Firefox launches but I cannot use terminal now because it is running the command for Firefox. As soon as I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> Firefox closes. Now I try to open it without terminal and it gives the same message that profile cannot be loaded.

How can I launch Firefox without getting my terminal occupied?

Comment: Check if `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` has its path set to the configuration folder ( at `abcdefgh.default`, replacing `abcdefgh` with the actual directory name). Sometimes, the easiest thing to do is simply delete the entire `~/.mozilla/` folder and start fresh. As for the Terminal-usage problem, simply press Ctrl-Shift-N to open a new window.

Comment: Great deleting the .mozilla folder worked man. Kudos

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to explain why you run Firefox as super-user? [That's a terrible idea](/q/270006/175814) and looks like a shoehorned solution to an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: In future, add `&` after command to run in background.

Comment: @matalak [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/q/1048932/#comment1712205_1048932) appears to be not only an answer but also [a correct one.](https://askubuntu.com/q/1048932/#comment1712430_1048932) Why not [write it up as such ?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) Cheers!

Comment: @ElderGeek Will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, there can be configuration errors when starting Firefox up for the first time. I've experienced very similar Mozilla-related difficulties with a few live operating systems in the past.

Check if the file `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` has its path set to the configuration folder; a folder called something like `abcdefgh.default` (replacing `abcdefgh` with the actual directory name).

Oftentimes, the easiest thing to do is simply delete the entire `~/.mozilla/` folder and start fresh.

As for the Terminal-usage problem, simply press Ctrl-Shift-N to open a new window.

Comment: Totally acceptable answer @matalak. Following your comment i was able to fix the issue but can you tell me where i can find this actual directory. Actually i deleted the .mozilla folder but before deleting i opened the profile.ini and it indeed was pointing to abcdefgh.default. What does the actual directory intend here??

Comment: @JotWaraich The .default directory in question can contain mass quantities of Firefox related files, extensions, cookies, etc.,etc. Rather than attempting do dig through all that stuff, the suggestion here is an effective and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me.

1.Kill all currently running process

```
killall firefox
killall thunderbird
```

2.Remove the cache Files

```
Note: Backup them before removing.

$ rm -rf ~/.mozilla/
$ rm -rf ~/.cache/mozilla/
```

3.Change the ownership of following folders

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cache/.mozilla/
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.mozilla/
```

** if the above step NOT successful, Then try following **

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache/.mozilla/
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.mozilla/
```

** if the above step NOT successful, Then try following **

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.cache/.mozilla/
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.mozilla/
```

4.If all above steps NOT successful, Then change entire cache folder permission

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cache
         or
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache
         or
$ sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to `/home/` and typed `ls -lah`
The permission for my user profile was `drw-------` 
So I changed that using:

```
chmod -R 777 /home/my.username/
```

Then type `firefox`

That solved it for me.

Comment: Doing a `chmod -R 777` on a user directory is a great way to lock yourself out of an account or break access to `sudo` operations. Sometimes it’s better to use a scalpel to remove a small problem than to swing an axe and create bigger ones 

Comment: Good to know. While none of the other methods worked for me, I had a feeling that this method might not be best practice.